# I don't understand why my MultiIndex slicing isn't working

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I've got a big DataFrame `track` with MultiIndexed columns, where

```
mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([masses,fluxes],names=['M','F'])
track = pd.DataFrame(dtype=float, index=range(0,100), columns=mindex)
```

I'm having a hard time recreating the error with a smaller DataFrame that I could print here, so I'll use the direct example which doesn't work.

The following give all me an error (`TypeError: '...' is and invalid key`):

```
track.loc[0,pd.IndexSlice[:,fluxes[-2]]]
```

and

```
track.loc[0,(slice(None),fluxes[-2])]
```

However, this doesn't:

```
track.loc[0][:,fluxes[-2]]
```

But I don't understand, are they not the same? I don't understand why the third example works, and the rest don't. What could be causing this bug?

Comment: The first two return DataFrames using pandas version 0.19. The third returns a Series.

Comment: Right, I am on 0.18. Still, is there something wrong with my syntax on the first two examples? Or would upgrading the pandas version help?

Comment: Your syntax is correct. Upgrading to version 0.19 should fix the problem.

Comment: Actually, turns out it's still not working in 0.19. :( I spoke too soon.

Comment: What is the value of `fluxes[-2]`? It might help if you post a runnable example which reproduces the error.